# How can I avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to a link by Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Using Angular 2, is there a setting to avoid adding prefix “**unsafe:**” to links. I need to set links for a protocol which is not whitelisted by default in Angular 2, but it is needed for our internal application, so the result is an invalid link:

```html
    <a href="unsafe:Notes://MYSERVER/C1256D3B004057E8" ..
```

In older Angular there was compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist, but I cannot find something similar in Angular 2.

Comment: I just had a whitespace in front of my URI

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Use the `DomSanitizer`:

```
import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
...
let sanitizedUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('Notes://MYSERVER/C1256D3B004057E8');
```

or create a method to return the sanitized url:

```
sanitize(url:string){
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

and then in your template:

`<a [href]="sanitize('Notes://MYSERVER/C1256D3B004057E8')" ..`

[Demo Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qgFwv1lBLpaDW0wsCYSs?p=preview)

Comment: Veri precise and complete instruction. Works perfectly. I wonder where you found this.... :)

Comment: Currently it's in the very top of [angular2 change log page](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). It's written for style sanitizing, but once you have `DomSanitizationService` the rest is just a matter of a ctrl+space :D

Comment: Before I saw your demo, I was failing hard to see that I missed some key imports: `@angular/platform-browser` and `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`.  
There was no way my URLs were going without `unsafe:` in their front.

Comment: @gustavohenke what did you import using `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic` when the DomSanitize is in `@angular/platform-browser` cuz I'm still having trouble?

Comment: @PaulG, this comment is from almost a year ago, from the times that Angular 2 wasn't even in final version, so things probably changed - and I'm not an Angular user anymore.

Comment: make sure to use property binding `<a [href]="sanitize(x)">` and not insertion `<a href="{{sanitize(x)}}">`

Comment: Or because we're in JavaScript, simply: `sanitize = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl` will work

Comment: Hey , I used your code but whenever i clicked on that link it automatically logged me out from my site . Any solution ??

Comment: make sure an url is safe before using `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`

Comment: You can also invoke DomSanitizer straight from a template expression (Angular 8):
```<a [href]="this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url)">
Go to URL
</a>
```

Comment: Please do not execute functions directly in templates, in Angular pipes are used for things like that so Change Detection can optimize the output.

Answer (score 55):

Another way is you can create a pipe service to change an unsafe URL to a safe URL, so there isn't any need to rewrite the code in all components.
Create a pipe service called `safe-url.pipe.ts`:

```javascript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(url) {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Then use it in your view.

Example:`<a [href]="'Notes://MYSERVER/C1256D3B004057E8' | safeUrl"></a>`

**NOTE**: Don't forget to inject this pipe service in your *app.module.ts* file:

```javascript
import { SafeUrlPipe } from './shared/safe-url.pipe'; // Make sure your safe-url.pipe.ts file path is matching.

@NgModule({ declarations: [SafeUrlPipe],...});
```

Comment: Perhaps, need put the 'href' into square brackets - [href], so Angular could execute it.

Comment: What is *"node"* (at the end) in this context? [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)? Something in Angular? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen he might meant to say "Angular Module". So in your app.module.ts file.

Comment: This is the right way of doing it, with a pipe. You can add pure: true, so it can only trigger when the value changes.