# Download File from href in angular 6

Tags: angular, file, download

```
 <a href="{{attachment.attachmentLocation}}" target="_blank" download>
{{attachment.fileName}} ({{ attachment.attachmentDate | date:'YYYY-MM-DD'}})</a>
```

I have tried to download by converting it to a blob file but its downloads the corrupt file.

In anchor tag href i get a path like `"C://assets/attachments/test.jpg"`. But when i click on the link it just opens in a new tab but doesnt get downloaded. Is there any way to download any type of file type from href?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: i do not get any error. It just opens in next tab.

Comment: getting any 'unsafe' prefix in the url?

Comment: i am debugging in production so, i dont get the unsafe prefix. If i use localhost i do get the error unsafe in front of the URL.

Comment: Use the `DomSanitizer` in your case See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-to-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-link-by-angular2) answer

Comment: yeah it does help me to get rid of the unsafe prefix in localhost. I am stuck with the download though.

Answer (score 0):

You either need a `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in your HTTP headers to make the browser treat the file as download or you can create attach a blob to the link (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864791/420587) answer)

Comment: I just wanted to download it by clicking the anchor tag and I wanted to download any type of file type.

Comment: Blobs work for any type of file. But you can't do this without javascript. See the linked answer you can add a click handler to the link and create the blob there.

Comment: how can i create my link to text, name, type. Sorry for the trouble. i get a link like "../asssets/attachments/test.jpg"