# Problem in converting unsafe to safe URL in Angular 8 using pipes

Tags: html, angular, angular-pipe

I am new to Angular, and I am trying to convert my unsafe URL to a safe URL. I searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-can-i-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-a-link-by-angular-2) to rectify this problem using pipe, but I don't see it converted to safe, may be something I am missing.

My *pipe.ts* file looks as below:

```
safe-url.pipe.ts

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

Part of my template looks as below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let myData of data"> // Data is coming the from component.ts file

    <td> <a href='my://problem/{{myData.Id}} | safeUrl'>myLink</a></td>
</tr>
```

In the UI, when I inspect, it appears to be like `unsafe: my://problem/55316480 | safeUrl`. But I expect it to appear as `my://problem/55316480`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let myData of data"> // data is coming from component.ts file

<td> <a href='my://problem/{{myData.Id}} | safeUrl'>myLink</a></td>
```

The issue is that 1) you are passing a string to href instead of an expression. 2) bypass the wrong property

Try

```
<td> <a [href]="('my://problem/' + myData.Id) | safeUrl">myLink</a></td>
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
```

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pi4mn8

Comment: I tried, now get this error:
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 16 in ['my://problem/{{myData.Id}}' | safeUrl] in....

Comment: Its not syntactically incorrect. ```unexpected token myData```

Comment: attached a demo and edited answer. bypass and template reference syntax issue.

Comment: Awesome ! . Worked.

Comment: What is the intent of "p" in ```p in the Markdown source (the first line)? In that position there would normally be something like `lang-none`, `lang-html`, `lang-javascript`, etc. You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58020588/edit) (e.g., to remove the "p" if it was not intended to be there).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td> <a [href]="('my://problem/' + myData.Id) | safeUrl">myLink</a></td>
```

Comment: doesn't work. See below error:

ERROR Error: Required a safe URL, got a HTML (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: Realized that apart from above, had to return 
```return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);```
in `pipe.ts`