# Allow a custom protocol in href

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have anchor tag and in href I have custom protocol. When I click it adds with a prefix unsafe.

```
Click <a href =“customProtocol://open/”>here</a> to open
```

How to avoid the unsafe prefix for this particular anchor tag alone .

Note : the custom protocol changes Dynamically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to a link by Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-can-i-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-a-link-by-angular-2)