# Angular: whitelist whatsapp:// protocol globally

Tags: angular, whitelist

I want to use protocols like whatsapp:// and fb-messenger:// in my angular app to open those apps on mobile devices.

In older AngularJS code, I could use `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|fb-messenger|whatsapp):/);` in the config() block of my app to whitelist those protocols.

When I look for a solution in Angular, I can only find  solutions to override the security for a specific url (eg. [How can I avoid adding prefix “unsafe” to a link by Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432609/how-can-i-avoid-adding-prefix-unsafe-to-a-link-by-angular-2) )

**Is there a way in Angular 9+ to whitelist extra protocols globally?**